# Mysterious interaction between lightgbm and sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, macos-sierra, lightgbm

Importing lightgbm on my system is somehow interfering with the performance of sklearn:

```
import lightgbm
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]
diabetes_X_train = diabetes_X[:-20]
diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]

for k in range(3):
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)
    print(str(regr.predict(diabetes_X_train)[0:1]))
```

The result is

```
[ 173.31236882]
[ 208.65797673]
[ 208.68957407]
```

which is very not what I expected. Commenting out the `import lightgbm` on the first line produces the desired result:

```
[ 210.80457868]
[ 210.80457868]
[ 210.80457868]
```

This is on macOS 10.12.6 with a recently installed Anaconda3 distribution followed by `pip install lightgbm`.  I also uninstalled lightgbm and built it from source, but that did not seem to make a difference. I'm unable to replicate this on ubuntu.

**Update**:  I completely uninstalled anaconda and homebrew and started all over with only homebrew + pip to manage everything. Looks like the error went away. But I'm still curious if this works for anyone on Mac + anaconda, as I prefer using anaconda.

Comment: Can you try to define a random seed (numpy.random.seed)and run again ? I will try to replicate this asap

Comment: I am not able to duplicate your results with scikit v 0.19.1 and python 2. With the lightgbm imported or not, I am getting the second set of scores. Can you clarify a bit more. Is this the only code you are using or anything else above it? What versions of scikit and lightgbm are you using?